# Writing metadata with xattr not working

Tags: finder, metadata

I do `xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment "This is a comment"  WnalU.png` but when I look at the file comments:

[image]

I tried restarting Finder and nothing.

I've googled about writing metadata, and aside from all the programs that I need to download, `xattr` was the only builtin solution, but maybe I'm taking the wrong approach?

Comment: Works here.  Don't know what else to say.  macOS 12.6.1

Comment: What filesystem is the test file on?  I tested on APFS.

Comment: Hello @MarcWilson! `Apple_APFS`

Comment: same here I'm on 12.6.1 and finder doesn't reflect the update. If I use xattr to print the attribute, it shows that it has been changed but finder doesn't show it. I relaunched finder, still same issue.